WYSIWYG editor on TranslatableType custom field
I added an extra translatable field in the categories called "Description footer" but I'm having trouble using the WYSIWYG editor on that field.
I use Prestashop 1.7.8.8 with Elementor addon and there are 4 active languages
    use PrestaShopBundle\Form\Admin\Type\FormattedTextareaType;
    use PrestaShopBundle\Form\Admin\Type\TranslatableType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

    public function hookActionCategoryFormBuilderModifier(array $params)
    {
        /** @var \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder $formBuilder */
        $formBuilder = $params['form_builder'];
        $locales = $this->get('prestashop.adapter.legacy.context')->getLanguages(); 
 
        $formBuilder->add('description_footer',
            // cf. https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/form/types-reference/
            TranslatableType::class,
            [
                'label' => $this->l('Description footer'),
                'type' => FormattedTextareaType::class,
                'required' => false,
                'locales' => $locales
            ]
        );

        $category = new Category((int)$params['id']);
        $params['data']['description_footer'] = $category->description_footer;
 
        $formBuilder->setData($params['data']);
    }

i get this


Solved using class TranslateType::class instead TranslatableType::class
    $formBuilder->add('description_footer',
    // cf. https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/components/form/types-reference/
    TranslateType::class,
    [
        'label' => $this->l('Descrizione footer'),
        'type' => FormattedTextareaType::class,
        'required' => false,
        'locales' => $locales,
        'hideTabs' => false,
    ]
);

